# Python: Why are these identical looking strings evaluated as not identical

Tags: python

I'm doing a little fun cryptanalysis exercise.
I the exercise, I get a txt file full of ciphertexts, where one ciphertext is encrypted by xor'ing with a single character.
I have made some python which solves the issue:

```
import enchant 

d = enchant.Dict("en_US")

def decrypt(c):
    l = len(c)

    for i in range(100):
        tmpKey = [i] * l 
        res = xor(tmpKey , c)
        
        Sprime = str(bytes(res))[2:][:-1]
        try:
            B = False

            split = Sprime.split()
            for s in split:
                if (d.check(s)):
                    B = True
                else:
                    B = False
                    break    
            if B:
                print(Sprime)
        except:
            continue
    
def xor(b1, b2):
    b = bytearray(len(b1))
    for i in range(len(b1)):
        b[i] = b1[i] ^ b2[i]
    return b

ccfile = open("4.txt", "r")

for aline in ccfile:
    decrypt(bytearray.fromhex(aline))
ccfile.close()
```

This produces a long list of decrypted plaintexts. Here is an excerpt of the output:

```
 ...
 B 95ME\x03\x05\x15:\x02>\x00E\x17X\x1a\x1d\x00\xae2-B' \x1a]\x02H
n \xd93\x10.X\xff\xd7\x19|/?;)vp^3? a|\x19m2\x01\xd1#|
Now that the party is jumping\n
L \xaf\rqP\x08\x14UG\xe3\\\x15sC]t_\xa8\x13M~Mm\xae{\\BJ\x11
4 GN\r*@\xf1\x17\xe6\xe2\n*\x1f*\xf3\x00\xfa:\x1ebQ\rN\x07C$\xfe#\x06
3 04;&\x0eN\x17T3\x04(\x11JA\x03\xf4[)[SV\x1d2\x06\x0fL9?
...
```

And here we see the plaintext `"Now that the party is jumping\n"`. Which is great.

My problem is that I would like my code to not only decrypt and show me all the texts, but also find valid plaintexts.

I the code you can see I have tried adding something that should catch the plaintext in question. This keeps not working for whatever reason!

I have this little toy example where I try to distinguish the plaintext that I am trying to find:

```
d = enchant.Dict("en_US")
B = False
split = "Now that the party is jumping\n".split()
print(split)
for s in split:
    if (d.check(s)):
        B = True
    else:
        B = False 
        break   

# If B is true, then the plaintext is valid english
```

And this works when I hardcode the string. But as soon as I implement "in action" then it doesnt work.
i Then also notice that when I compare the two strings, the hardcoded one, and the one that is simply output when running the program:

```
    if (Sprime ==  "Now that the party is jumping\n"):
        print("should be true at some point")
```

Then this statement is never triggered. "Now that the party is jumping\n"  is not the same as "Now that the party is jumping\n". What? why is this?

**EDIT**

The original problem can be [found here][1].

I have now tested around a bit more, and compared the two strings character-wise.
I now have this code for playing around:

```
from os import stat
import enchant 


d = enchant.Dict("en_US")

def decrypt(c):
    l = len(c)

    for i in range(100):
        tmpKey = [i] * l 
        res = xor(tmpKey , c)
        
        Sprime = str(bytes(res))[2:][:-1]
        state = False
        if (Sprime.startswith("Now")): #==  "Now that the party is jumping\n"):
            state = True
            print(Sprime)
            for s1,s2 in zip(Sprime, "Now that the party is jumping\n" +
            ""):
                bb = s1 == s2
                print(s1 + " ^ " + s2 + " = " + str(bb))
        try:
            if state:
                print(Sprime)
            B = False

            split = Sprime.split()
            for s in split:
                if (d.check(s)):
                    B = True
                else:
                    B = False
                    break    
            if B:
                print(Sprime)
        except:
            continue
    
def xor(b1, b2):
    b = bytearray(len(b1))
    for i in range(len(b1)):
        b[i] = b1[i] ^ b2[i]
    return b

ccfile = open("4.txt", "r")

for aline in ccfile:
    decrypt(bytearray.fromhex(aline))
ccfile.close()
```

When my hardcoded string ends with "\n" then the comparison gives me the following output:

```
Now that the party is jumping\n
N ^ N = True
o ^ o = True
w ^ w = True
  ^   = True
t ^ t = True
h ^ h = True
a ^ a = True
t ^ t = True
  ^   = True
t ^ t = True
h ^ h = True
e ^ e = True
  ^   = True
p ^ p = True
a ^ a = True
r ^ r = True
t ^ t = True
y ^ y = True
  ^   = True
i ^ i = True
s ^ s = True
  ^   = True
j ^ j = True
u ^ u = True
m ^ m = True
p ^ p = True
i ^ i = True
n ^ n = True
g ^ g = True
\ ^ = False
```

So they are not the same because the incoming string has a `\` at the end, whereas the hardcoded string interprets the `\n` as an actual breakline, and not string.
Fine enough, so I try change my hardcod string to `"Now that the party is jumping".
However when I try to test these two strings for equality, they still do not match. What in the world is going on?
[1]: https://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/4

Comment: Compare it character by character, use `list` to split into individual unicode characters and inspect visually

Comment: `str(bytes(res))[2:][:-1]` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: what does it do then?

Answer (score 0):

The following works just as expected (Fedora 34, python3-3.9.5-2.fc34.x86_64):

```
import enchant

d = enchant.Dict("en_US")
phrase = input("Enter a phrase: ")
split = phrase.split()
print(split)

B = True
for s in split:
    B = B and d.check(s)
print(B)
```

Note you could just asign the result of `d.check(s)` to your boolean `B`, no need to use the `if` to figure out what value to assign. Here I just accumulate the result. If it is a longer text, you might want to bail out as soon as you find a `False`.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think this really answers my question. I'll add an edit to the question